# Is there a way to detect what device a user is using?

Tags: javascript, user-agent

Say I wanted to provide a string to the user, "You are using a..." followed by their device.

For example a Google Nexus 7, Dell Chromebook 13, Samsung Galaxy J3, Apple Macbook Pro... whatever their device is. Specifically the model of their device.

I've seen Spotify do this, for example. Is this possible using JS?

I'm aware that user agent sniffing exists, but it's not as detailed as I'd like it to be.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.whatsmyua.info/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

or you can use whith jQuery this:

```
var customizeForDevice = function(){
    var ua = navigator.userAgent;
    var checker = {
      iphone: ua.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad)/),
      blackberry: ua.match(/BlackBerry/),
      android: ua.match(/Android/)
    };
    if (checker.android){
        $('.android-only').show();
    }
    else if (checker.iphone){
        $('.idevice-only').show();
    }
    else if (checker.blackberry){
        $('.berry-only').show();
    }
    else {
        $('.unknown-device').show();
    }
}
```